# Filling text boxes with 0 when nothing is in them

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm learning Action Script 3 and I need to put a 0 in a text box if nothing is in the input text box. So far I started with thing but it doesn't work...

```
var courage:int = parseInt(courage_txt.text);

function checkTraits(e:Event){

stage.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkTraits);

if(courage_txt.text == ""){
    courage = 0;

}
```

I know I'm missing something I just don't know what!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkTraits);

function checkTraits(e:Event) {

     if(courage_txt.text == "") {
         courage_txt.text = "0";
     }

     courage = parseInt(courage_txt.text);
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something! That really helps! Thank you!